# Зазор в виде бордера на картинке

Tags: img

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто знает почему появляется такой бордер сверху и слева? единственный момент, на картинке добавлена маска (-webkit-mask-image) с анимацией, то есть переливается бесконечно. Проблема обнаружена в chrome и то в единичном случае. 
Стили картинки:

```
height: 80px;
margin-bottom: 1rem
```

Проверить не могу, исчезает ли проблема без маски... ибо у меня такого бордера не наблюдается

Comment: для воспроизведения у себя, масштаб пробовали разный?

Comment: да, но не помогает